# Show Integer choice value as Characters (not integer) in Admin

Tags: python, django, django-admin

I'm trying to display values from a choices field. Using the below methods, causes the "Store" model to break (clicking on it from Admin)

Error is:

```
TypeError __str__ returned non-string (type int)
```

When I change **str** to **int** the error stops- but it doesn't display the region choice (just "Region Object").

```
country_list = ['Global', 'Australia', 'United Kingdom', 'United States']

Region_CHOICES = tuple(enumerate(country_list, start=1))

class Region (models.Model):
    region = models.IntegerField(choices=Region_CHOICES)
    def __str__(self):
        return self.region

class Store(models.Model):
    store_name = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    region = models.ManyToManyField(Region, blank=True)
```

How can I get it to correctly return the Region as a choice (from the list of words, not the integer itself)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue is that your `__str__` method *must* return an object of type `str`.

Since the index is what's stored in `self.region`, you can simply do a lookup:

```
class Region(models.Model):
    ...
    def __str__(self):
        return Region_CHOICES[self.region][1]
```

Comment: This gives me a TypeError too- __str__ returned non-string (type tuple). Here is the full traceback http://dpaste.com/0XJN9NR

Comment: Ah, sorry about that. Updated the response.

Comment: `return self.get_region_display()` will also work. See https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/models/instances/#django.db.models.Model.get_FOO_display

Answer (score 0):

Just type cast to string

```
def __str__(self):
    return str(self.region)
```

This works for me